# How to update data in excel File using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, excel-interop

This Question might be repeated, But I couldn't get solution regarding my problem so far. I'm new to Interop. I'm using excel file (as a database). 
Here is data presentation in excel file

[image]

in my data If Card ID repeated then I need to increment '1' in Counter in the same row, similarly I need to fetch IP address of same row..

I'm using Interop Excel approach to insert data in excel file..
Kindly tell me how can I perform that update operation to that excel file through C# (WPF)

Sorry for bad English..

Thanks

Comment: Using excel as database makes it more difficult. Try a database, mssql-express or ms-access for example.

Comment: An option maybe to convert it to csv?

Comment: You are right.. but it's client's requirement to use Excel

Comment: It would probably be easier to use a real datastore like Stefan suggested and generate an Excel report for your client.

Comment: There are way better alternative then using interop to manipulate excel files. For your use case, I suggest to keep your data in an mssql database and create an excel report. But if you absolutely must do it in c#, at least use the openXML api and not interop.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using [Closed XML](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml)

You write to the file directly and don't need Excel. It will need to be the latest version of an Excel file to work (The open xml standard).

Comment: You can also use microsoft interop library if you have office installed. Closed XML is a little more wordy but as Clayton stated you don't need Excel installed to utilize it. I prefer closed XML.

Answer (score 2):

Epplus.dll or npoi.dll will also read/write to excel files w/o excel.

Answer (score 1):

Save the data in an XML or JSON file, then when you want to visualize them you create the excel file from these data, so you will have a very light file and easy to read and update if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this specifically through wpf, but you can access powershell cmdlets through .net and powershell has commands for retrieving and writing Excel data.

That said, my experience has been it's very tedious and inconsistent with bugs. I would tell your client that using an Excel file as a database is impossible and certainly prone to failure in practice.

For one thing you will run into read/write restrictions if it is used by anything else.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to use comercial libraries, you can try to use [Aspose.Cells](https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsnet/Home). It has rich cells API and able to work without Excel interop API.